# What is known about pressure on Klobuchar and Buttigieg to drop out and endorse Biden?

Tags: united-states, democratic-party, campaigning, democratic-primary, joe-biden

Before 2020 Super Tuesday, Amy Klobuchar, Pete Buttigieg, and Joe Biden were seen as ‘splitting the center democratic’ vote.

At the same time, Bernie Sanders had the largest consolidated block of left-of-center primary voters, and was leading shortly before the Super Tuesday elections.

This dynamic may have continued past Super Tuesday, but Sander’s fortune changed nearly overnight as Klobuchar and Buttigieg dropped out and endorsed Biden shortly before Super Tuesday.

With the two centrist competitors  gone, Biden went on a clear path for Democratic nomination.

**Question: What is known about any pressure Klobuchar and Buttigieg campaigns were under to drop out and endorse Biden, before the Super Tuesday elections?**

Answer (score 6):

Klobuchar never made much of an impression in the race.

Buttigieg did surprisingly well in the beginning, but, as a relative unknown, bet on a strategy of concentrating on early small races (Iowa) and then becoming the de-facto leader of the non-Sanders camp.  Once Biden nuked Sanders in Super Tuesday delegates, the scrappy up-and-comer-with-momentum image went out the window.

The Democratic party probably thought it wise to close ranks around best-chance contenders and avoid too much image fratricide from low-probability contenders.  Klobuchar can't have been too sore about it as she was considered for VP.

None of this is really that unusual or unexpected with POTUS primaries, and, as far as I am concerned, unless he throws us some more red meat to whet appetite for this question, the OP is just fishing.

p.s. I originally wrote this as a comment, because I did not feel it worthwhile to "reward" this question (which I did not downvote), but someone deleted all comments.

p.p.s.  Even Sanders threw in his hat relatively shortly afterwards, so, besides Covid, he must have also thought maximizing November chances was worthwhile.